# Extract p-value from GARCH model (package rugarch)

Tags: p-value, arch

I want to extract the p value of the coefficients of my garch model.

Here is an replicable exemple:

```
library(rugarch) 
y<-rnorm(1:100)
 spec <- ugarchspec(variance.model = list(model = "sGARCH", garchOrder = c(1, 1), 
                                             submodel = NULL, external.regressors = NULL, variance.targeting = FALSE), 
                       mean.model = list(armaOrder = c(1, 0), external.regressors = NULL, include.mean=T), distribution.model ="norm")


 garch <- ugarchfit(spec=spec, data = y , solver = 'hybrid')
```

Results gave me:

### Optimal Parameters

```
   Estimate  Std. Error  t value Pr(>|t|)
```

mu      0.091862    0.083258  1.10334 0.269880 
ar1    -0.165456    0.098624 -1.67764 0.093418 
omega   0.033234    0.050870  0.65332 0.513550 
alpha1  0.041305    0.051530  0.80158 0.422793 
beta1   0.920773    0.079976 11.51312 0.000000

I can extract the coef by using:

```
coef(garch)
```

But does anyone know how can I extract the pvalue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

you can extract the a matrix of coefficients with: 
garch@fit$robust.matcoef (or garch@fit$matcoef but generally speaking robust errors preferred)

Then normal matrix indexing will allow you to retrieve values of interest, such that for retrieving p-values, you will want the retrieve the fourth column as follows:

garch@fit$robust.matcoef[,4]

Hope this helps.